# Sub Tasks in Trello

Tags: trello

Can there be a sub tasks and sub-sub tasks to the Cards in Trello?
I have created a board and am adding tasks as cards. The tasks have various Sub-tasks, is there a way to add them as sub-cards?

Comment: Hi Nitisha, I'd be very interested to know if you found a solution for this? 
 I tried Hello Epics mentioned below and was not satisfied by its functionality. Thanks!

Comment: Related: [Task Dependencies - Trello Help](https://help.trello.com/article/1165-task-dependencies "Task Dependencies - Trello Help")

Answer (score 3):

In the past few weeks Trello announced a new power-up called "Hello Epics" that sounds to do exactly what you are looking for:
https://blog.trello.com/trello-card-dependencies-hello-epics-power-up

Disclaimer: I am not in any way affiliated with Trello or Hello Epics, just a very happy user.

Answer (score 0):

We've released a free Power-Up that allows creating hierarchies and tracking progress of epics on Trello boards. You can learn more at https://screenful.com/epics-for-trello

Comment: Hi Sami, without more information, this looks a bit like an advertisement.  Could you explain how it addresses the issue of the "sub-cards" in the question?  (I'm not a Trello user, so perhaps what you said suffices, but just a bit more explanation would turn this into an answer rather than just a plug)